# How to access the scope of a parent's controller's in a directive's controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have a custom directive nested in a parent div who's controller sets a variable *value* to its scope, such as:

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <p>{{data}}</p>
    <myDirective oncolour="green" offcolour="red" data="data"></myDirective>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope){
   $scope.data= 1;
});

app.directive("myDirective", function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope: {
           oncolour: '@',
           offcolour: '@',
           data: '='
       },
       template: '<p>{{data}} is {{state}}</p>',
       controller: function($scope){

           console.log($scope.data); //undefined!

          /* logic to set $scope.state depending on $scope.data */

       };
   };
});
```

I can pass the value of *data* to the directive  as I can see the **{{data}}** off the template being parsed correctly.

However, **$scope.data** is undefined in the directive's controller. I need to apply some logic there depending on this variable like *if data==1, then state="on", else state="off"*, so I can then apply the *oncolour* and *offcolour* appropriately.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: My best bet is that the variable is being shadowed as you pass data directly (don't know the content of it). Would you mind trying to wrap your data in an object literal? Then in your HTML pass it as data="wrapper.data"

Comment: Oh sorry I can see the content of data of course :-D my bad. Still sticking with my theory though. Another, yet more expensive option is to add a watch on data inside your directive. Should not be necessary though.

Comment: I would use the link funktion and access attr, elem and scope. Access data by scope.data

Comment: @marcel scope.data is undefined in link function too

Answer (score 2):

"transclude" options is necessary:

```
   transclude: true,
   controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
       console.log($scope.data);
   }],
```

Comment: take a look at the fiddle

Comment: Ah... Thanks. Wierd that it doesn't work for me... The only difference I can see is that you added a transclude: yes

Comment: If you use link you don't need to transclude, otherwise yes

Comment: Link won't keep looking for changes in the scope, which means you have to setup a watch for it. Also not a fan of transcluding, not something that should be needed in this scenario.

Comment: In this scenario yes. Updated the answer to leave only the best reply for this case

Answer (score 0):

You miss the `$` before the scope in your directive. The reason you will have undefined is because in the directive `$scope` is not the same as return `scope`. You have to match them.

```
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    $scope: {
       oncolour: '@',
       offcolour: '@',
       data: '='
    },
    template: '<p>{{data}} is {{state}}</p>',
    controller: function($scope){

       console.log($scope.data); //undefined!

      /* logic to set $scope.state depending on $scope.data */

    };
   };
});
```

Comment: If I do that, $scope.data is still undefined and {{data}} from directive template doesn't even get parsed

Answer (score 0):

change `$scope` to `scope`, take a look to [angular directive documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), goto end of page and check sample code

```
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope: {
           oncolour: '@',
           offcolour: '@',
           data: '='
       },
       template: '<p>{{data}} is {{state}}</p>',
       controller: function(scope){

           console.log(scope.data); //undefined!

          /* logic to set $scope.state depending on $scope.data */

       };
   };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that the binding is failing as data is a primitive, see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

**Try and change:**

```
app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope){
   $scope.data= 1;
});
```

And

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <p>{{data}}</p>
    <myDirective oncolour="green" offcolour="red" data="data"></myDirective>
</div>
```

**Into:**

```
app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope){
   $scope.data= {
      value: 1
   };
});
```

And

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <p>{{data.value}}</p>
    <myDirective oncolour="green" offcolour="red" data="data.value"></myDirective>
</div>
```

Comment: Just tried wrapping the primitive in an object as suggested here. Doesn't seems to change anything... $scope.data in still undefined

Answer (score 0):

Check AngluarJS [normalization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

The directive elements name is wrong:

```
<myDirective ... >
```

It should be

```
<my-directive ...>
```

And make sure to access scope instead of $scope.